# Failed messages on Twilio

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I built a whatapp chatbot using flask and Twilio, but seem to getting failed messages on when I check my console. The status appears as failed with an unknown error. When I check my debugger I see the error message

```
HTTP retrieval failure
```

I started getting these errors after making a few changes to my flask app. I tried undoing all the changes but now instead of getting received as the status, the status now appears as failed. I tried restarted my ngrok and changing the url on my Twilio but this hasn't changed anything either.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
import random
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    if incoming_msg == 'help':
        #return options available
        output = 'This is a chatbot designed to send statistics, linear algebra and general programming problem questions. Please type in either "Python", "Statistics" or Linear Algebra" to get a random problem.'
        msg.body(output)
        responded = True
    if 'python' in incoming_msg:
        with open("C://Users//User//Downloads//python_test.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            code = random.choice(lines)
            msg.body(code)
            responded = True
    if 'quote' in incoming_msg:
        # return a quote
        r = requests.get('https://api.quotable.io/random')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            quote = f'{data["content"]} ({data["author"]})'
        else:
            quote = 'I could not retrieve a quote at this time, sorry.'
        msg.body(quote)
        responded = True
    if 'thegradientboost' in incoming_msg:
        message = 'Test \
                  '. Additional text' \
                  'More text,' \
                  'end of text.' \
                  'a bit more text' \
                  'conclusion.'
        msg.body(message)
        responded = True
    if not responded:
        msg.body('Word not included.')
    return str(resp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the failure path? All words in Body you check for? Do you see errors in the terminal shell you run the Python application from when you send an inbound WhatsApp?

Comment: @Alan no errors in the terminal shell, everything seems to be running from that perspective. Not sure what you mean by failure path, I don't see an error message in my debugger. but my log shows the a failed status with error 30008 unknown error

Comment: In terminal shell, you see successful responses? What are you sending in via WhatsApp, what keyword (quote, ?). You still connected to the Sandbox?
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2020 21:56:42] "POST /bot HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2020 21:56:55] "POST /bot HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2020 21:56:59] "POST /bot HTTP/1.1" 200 -